# Force native Facebook app login for web application (Android WiFi Sign in)

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, wifi

We've built a web application which let you *login with Facebook to get **WiFi** access.* Since (i think) **Android 4.4** you have this **WiFi** Signin dialog within Android.

If we use this 'popup' for signing in with Facebook, we are always redirected to the Facebook website.

Can we somehow force the application to first check for native Facebook apps before getting to the website?

Comment: Try https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android   in Access Tokens and Profiles Area, hopfully it helps you.

Comment: Thanks @SalmanAslam I will look into that one!

Comment: @SalmanAslam The link your provided only works for Android, but we have a web application. So we use the PHP SDK, is there something alike for the PHP SDK?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web.     2 options from you. Either use javescript facebook sdk or native login..

Comment: @SalmanAslam ok thanks for the answers, i will look into this!!

Comment: @Jonatan Hey mate, did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Jonatan did you ever solve this issue?